# JPanel JFrame separate classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm a Java beginner who is starting out with making a GUI for my program and I am stuck on `JFrames` and `JPanels`. My goal is to make a `JFrame` with several `JPanels` in it, and every `JPanel` has its own class.

I have made a start, but I cannot seem to get it to work. My code is as follows:

This is the JFrame class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame f;

    public TestFrame(){
        f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new TestPanel();
        p.setVisible(true);
        f.add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestFrame();
    }
}
```

And this is the JPanel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton b;
    private JTextField t;

    public TestPanel(){
        b = new JButton("bla");
        t = new JTextField("blaadda");
        add(b);
        add(t);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor should not be creating a new JFrame. Your class (`TestFrame`) is what you will be using to create your window, not the JFrame class. You may be having other errors, but the most obvious one is that

```
public TestFrame(){
    f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(600, 400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p = new TestPanel();
    p.setVisible(true);
    f.add(p);
}
```

Should be

```
public TestFrame(){
    //Don't create a new JFrame, you're already creating a TestFrame!
    //call all methods on the TestFrame, not the JFrame
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(600, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p = new TestPanel();
    p.setVisible(true);
    add(p);
}
```

Your TestPanel constructor looks good. I would recommend making any Panels in your TestFrame fields rather than temporary variables in the constructor, however.

Then create your window like this:

```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
  {
      public void run()
      {
          new TestFrame();
      }
  }
```

Finally if all else fails try calling `setEnabled(true)` in your constructors.

Hope any of this helps, I have since left Swing for OpenGL but I remember how frustrating it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `setVisible` as your last method in the `TestFrame` constructor:

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

Also there is no need to make this the call for your `JPanel` as the frame will make all its child components visible when it becomes visible itself:

```
p.setVisible(true);
```

so this line could be removed.

---

Also you have `TestFrame` extending `JFrame`. This creates 2 frames, one of which is never displayed. It is sufficient to create the frame in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.add(p);
p.repaint();
p.revalidate();
```

Comment: You should add context to this answer; why does it solve the problem as presented?